# Trying to unload unmanaged and managed third party dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dispose

Can you tell me please what is the best way to make garage collector to unload unmanaged/managed third party dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to unload managed assembly in .NET. The only option is to unload the entire `AppDomain`. See also:

- [Unloading an Assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/07/08/unloading-an-assembly.aspx) - Suzanne Cook's .NET CLR Notes

Answer (score 0):

Managed code loads into Windows process into a 'default app domain', which is never unloaded until the process terminates.

CLR cant unload a single assembly; however a single AppDomain can be unloaded.

Calling AddRef & Release methods on ICLRRuntimeHost has no effects. [CLR is just like a COM Server]

Check MSDN link Why isn't there an Assembly.Unload method? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2004/05/31/145105.aspx

To release unmanaged resources use IDisposable Interface.

A nice article on MSDN about Garbage Collection
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottholden/archive/2004/12/28/339733.aspx